# How to implement LoDash's sampleSize with Ramda in a functional JS way?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to implement the LoDash's [sampleSize](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/sampleSize.js) method with Ramda in a **functional way**.

Any ideas? I'm totally stuck at going any further than getting a `randomIndex` from the given array. How do I loop through with recursion using Ramda?

So, the function would look like this:

```
export const sampleSize = curry((size, list) => compose(
  // two paths of code
  // one to splice messages at the randomIndex
  // recursion with the spliced array until length === size
  randomIndex
)(list))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably not use Ramda to do this.  Note that I'm one of the founders of Ramda and a big fan.  But Ramda is designed for functional programming.  One of the chief tenets of functional programming is to use pure functions, ones which use no inputs outside their arguments and have no effects except to return a value.  For the same input, they should then always return the same output.  This will not work when the code is supposed to do something randomly.<sup>1</sup>

You could use code like what lodash does for this, an early-return version of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) or you could use something like this, which also keeps its results in the order found in the original array:

```js
const sampleSize = (size, list, collected = []) => size < 1 || list.length < 1
  ? collected
  : size >= list.length
    ? [...collected, ...list] // or throw error?
    : Math.random() < size / list.length
      ? sampleSize(size -1, list.slice(1), [...collected, list[0]])
      : sampleSize(size, list.slice(1), collected)

console.log(sampleSize(4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
console.log(sampleSize(4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
console.log(sampleSize(4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))

console.log(sampleSize(0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
console.log(sampleSize(10, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
console.log(sampleSize(20, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
```

This was written in a hurry, and may have bugs, but it should be pretty close.  The idea is to check each element one at a time to see if it should be included, adjusting the chance according to how many are left to include and how many are left in the list.

A Fisher-Yates version would be more efficient than this, especially as this uses recursion which might even today not be efficiently optimized by engines, even if the specification has called for it for several years now.  But Fisher-Yates does not keep the original sort order.  If you want that, this one might be for you.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that at one point, Ramda did have a [random number extension](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/commit/560052586b3e7590bcac718ed2d6e933fd640df7), but that has long been discarded.  It used a repeatable pseudo-random number generator, which sounds almost like an oxymoron, but makes sense when working with pure functions.

Comment: I take your point about randomness and pure function but are we saying that one should never try dealing with random values in a functional way?

Comment: @customcommander Just wrap random numbers in a type that has a functor/monad constraint. Randomness is just the effect of that functorial/monadic type and as with all functors/monads you can't get a value out, but you can lift functions so that they can work with random values. [More](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/202915).

Comment: @reify Interesting! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

First let's define a function that will return a random number between `min` (inclusive) and `max` (exclusive). We can curry it because `min` will always be set to 0,
while `max` will always be set to the new list's length - 1

```
const random = curry((min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) - min));
```

Then we need a function that will take a list and returns two things (in an array):

1. a randomly picked element
2. a new list without that element

```
const takeFromList = converge(
  converge(pair, [nth, flip(remove)(1)]) [compose(random(0), length), identity]);
```

Putting everything together:

As you can see if the requested sample size is bigger than the actual list size, it will return the entire list but in random order.

```js
const {curry, min, nth, identity, converge, pair, flip, compose, length, remove, flatten} = R;

const random = curry((min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) - min));
const takeFromList = converge(converge(pair, [nth, flip(remove)(1)]), [compose(random(0), length), identity]);

const sampleSize = curry((size, list) => {
  const [el, newList] = takeFromList(list);
  const len = min(size, list.length);
  return len - 1 > 0 ? flatten([el, sampleSize(len - 1, newList)]) : [el];
});

console.log(sampleSize(2, [1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(sampleSize(2, [1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(sampleSize(2, [1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(sampleSize(20, [1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(sampleSize(20, [1,2,3,4,5]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Quick question: Is it okay to have a few assignment operators like in your `sampleSize` function (which sort of makes it imperative) and still call it `functional`?

Comment: AFAIK functional programming is about programming with expressions not statements. The only statement that we are making here is the declaration of a few constants with `const` (not to be confused with the assignment operator `=`) Using a function as a reusable unit of work is such an expression, however operators such as the ternary operator are valid functional constructs too. I bet that a few people doing functional programming assign functions to variables or constants so that they can be reused without even noticing the idiomatic conflict, and that's fine IMHO.

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed: many -- probably most -- functional programming languages and libraries include assignment.  Many do not allow for re-assignment.  Ramda, like most JS attempts at FP have no problem even with re-assignment within the bounds of an internal function.  Thus Ramda is written with `while`-loops and not the deep recursion still not optimized for by JS engines.

Comment: @customcommander: While using expressions instead of statements is common in FP, I would say that more central are the use of pure functions, and the immutability of values.

Comment: @ScottSauyet That's also very true, thanks for pointing that out. Since the OP asked for a solution with Ramda, I suggested one but I also agree that Ramda isn't strictly necessary in this case. Good feedback as always, thanks ;)